# When to updateMatrixWorld to have localToWorld and worldToLocal properly working?

Tags: three.js

I'll explain the problem I'm facing, cause probably I'm doing something wrong.

I have some models in blender, these are exported to json and used in three.js. In these models there are some planes, which then in js are replaced on the flight with another mesh to enable a cloth simulation.

The models can rotate once in the scene, and these planes being children of the models will also rotate. Moreover, the original planes from blender could have some rotation applied.

However we want the wind to be global, so for each plane and each frame, a global (world) wind direction vector is cloned and then transformed into the local coordinates of each plane, so that cloth particles can be moved correctly.

This is accomplished simply with :

```
globalDir = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1); // Wind from north
// ...
var localDir = plane.worldToLocal(globalDir.clone());
// use localDir vector for moving around vertices base don wind
```

This "works", meaning that all clothes children of a single model are aligned to the same global wind, but :

- nothing else changing, only refreshing the page, given the same values for the globalDir vector, the wind direction is always different.
- from model to model, the direction is different.

It seems to be all about how the world matrix gets updated relatively to the object hierarchy, on the order the models are loaded and added, and so on.

I've been trying to add and remove calls to updateMatrix and updateMatrixWorld everywhere around, I'm asking for guidelines about how the methods updateMatrix, updateMatrixWorld, localToWorld and worldToLocal are supposed to be used.

Comment: 1. The renderer calls `updateMatrixWorld()` for every object in the scene graph every frame. 2. Avoid "new" and "clone" in tight loops; create one object and reuse it. 3. It is better to show your code instead of describing it.